# Azure Devops YAML Pipeline - Deployment Job does not respect the timeoutInMinutes property

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am using Yaml pipelines in Azure Dev Ops, and have a multi-stage build/deploy.

Based on the documentation here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/phases?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

It suggests a `job` has a property of `timeoutInMinutes`.

We however have a `-Job`, which is followed by a `-Deployment` (which the docs say is just a special type of job). The deployment is executed on a Azure Devops Environment, which is just an Azure Deployment Agent on a self-hosted docker container.

The execution works fine but the job always times out at 60 minutes regardless.

Example YML

```yaml
 -jobs
  - job: JobA
        timeoutInMinutes: 30
        [...]
  - deployment: JobB
        timeoutInMinutes: 360
        dependsOn:
          - JobA
        environment:
          name: MyEnvironment
          resourceType: VirtualMachine
          tags: "TheAgent"
        strategy:
          runOnce:
            deploy:
              timeoutInMinutes: 360
              steps:
                 [... long running task...]
```

The issue is that the deployment job deploys and then has a task within it to run off some automated regression tooling which takes between 70-90 minutes.

`The job running on agent [name] ran longer than the maximum time of 60 minutes.`

I must be missing something surely? For a self-hosted agent there is no reason to have this limit? Is there an alternative to this?

Comment: Please set timeout on task level, note to also add timeout(larger) at job level for a check. On my side with self-hosted agent(VM type, not container), even without timeout setting, it can work than 60mins, hence please remote to the container, check if it is still working. I added the details in the reply, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/phases?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#timeouts), you can also set the timeout at `task` level in the deployment job.  Please remove `timeoutInMinutes` after `deploy:` as it's not the correct syntax.

[image]

sample as below:

```
  - deployment: JobB
    timeoutInMinutes: 360         # larger timeout than task
    dependsOn:
      - JobA
    environment:
      name: MyEnvironment
      resourceType: VirtualMachine
      tags: "TheAgent"
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - powershell: |
              long time job which more than 60mins
            timeoutInMinutes: 120           # define timeout on task level
```

Checked on my side, with deployment job which has a self-hosted agent(VM,not container), `even not have timeout in task level`, it can work more than 1hour. Hence, you can also check if the self-container is still working after 1hour.

[image]